# UWP Loop Fade Animation

Tags: xaml, animation, uwp, infinite-loop, windows-community-toolkit

I have a Pivot and its header template is a **user control** and I want to start a **continuous Flashing** ( Fade Out Fade In ) animation on it on a specific trigger and then also want to stop it on a specific trigger, while both of these triggers/events will happen in the ViewModel of the page. I can take care of the triggers but my only issue is I am not sure how to achieve the **infinite flashing behavior**. The header has to start flashing when I tell it to and has to keep flashing until I tell it to stop. I wonder if there is some sort of **Repeat** animation property in xaml but couldn't find that in xaml animations from **Community Toolkit**

**Queue** is the model class which defines the context of HeaderTemplate, so I've custom events to start and stop the flashing, because I have access to that Queue object instance within the ViewModel of my page.

All the custom logic happens in code behind of the User Control. Attached is the code I have tried below. I would prefer if this is somehow done all in xaml or mostly in xaml so I can avoid any infinite loops or memory leak risks. My current attempt just freezes the UI and rightly so as I am doing an infinite loop which makes stuff just weird.

### Code

**Pivot Header**

```
<Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="cad:Queue">
                <dataTemplates:HomePivotHeaderTemplate />
            </DataTemplate>
</Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
```

**Queue class**

```
public partial class Queue
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> StartFlash;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> StopFlash;

    public void OnStartFlash() => StartFlash?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    public void OnStopFlash() => StopFlash?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

**Triggers in ViewModel**

```
    public void StartFlashingPendingQueues()
    {
         PivotQueues.First()?.OnStartFlash();            
    }

    private void StopFlashingPendingQueues()
    {
         PivotQueues.First()?.OnStopFlash();
    }
```

**UserControl for Data Template**

```
 public sealed partial class HomePivotHeaderTemplate : UserControl
{
    public Queue VM => DataContext as Queue;
    private bool _IsFlashing;
    private bool _unLoaded;
    public HomePivotHeaderTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Loaded;
        Unloaded += HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Unloaded;
        DataContextChanged += (s, e) => Bindings.Update();
    }

    private void HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _unLoaded = true;
        Loaded -= HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Loaded;
        Unloaded -= HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Unloaded;
        VM.StartFlash -= VM_StartFlash;
        VM.StopFlash -= VM_StopFlash;
    }

    private void HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VM.StartFlash += VM_StartFlash;
        VM.StopFlash += VM_StopFlash;
        VM_Flashed();
    }

    private void VM_StopFlash(object sender, System.EventArgs e) => _IsFlashing = false;

    private void VM_StartFlash(object sender, System.EventArgs e) => _IsFlashing = true;

    private async Task VM_Flashed()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (_unLoaded)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_IsFlashing)
                {
                    await Block.Fade(value: 0f, duration: 500, delay: 0, easingType: EasingType.Linear, easingMode: EasingMode.EaseOut).Then().Fade(value: 1f, duration: 500, delay: 0, easingType: EasingType.Linear, easingMode: EasingMode.EaseIn).StartAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit 1

If I can somehow figure out how to give infinite flashing animation to the textblock I can take care of the rest. basically I could just have 2 textblocks identical, one of them will be flashing other won't, and I can toggle their visibility based on triggers in my viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was just overthinking it. It was a simple **DoubleAnimation** in a **StoryBoard**

### UserControl code behind

```
public sealed partial class HomePivotHeaderTemplate : UserControl
{
    public Queue VM => DataContext as Queue;
    public HomePivotHeaderTemplate()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Loaded;
        Unloaded += HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Unloaded;
        DataContextChanged += (s, e) => Bindings.Update();
    }

    private void HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Loaded;
        Unloaded -= HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Unloaded;
        VM.StartFlash -= VM_StartFlash;
        VM.StopFlash -= VM_StopFlash;
    }

    private void HomePivotHeaderTemplate_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        VM.StartFlash += VM_StartFlash;
        VM.StopFlash += VM_StopFlash;
    }

    private void VM_StopFlash(object sender, System.EventArgs e) => FlashStoryBoard.Stop();

    private void VM_StartFlash(object sender, System.EventArgs e) => FlashStoryBoard.Begin();
}
```

### UserControl Xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="FlashStoryBoard">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Block" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            Duration="0:0:2"
            From="1"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever"
            To="0.2" />
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<TextBlock x:Name="Block"
    Text="{x:Bind VM.Name}" />
```